# Assigning values from data frame to vector in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame as below:

```
data <- data.frame(name = c("a", "b"),
                   value = c("apple", "ball"))
```

Now from this data I want to create a vector as follows:

```
transformed_data <- c( a = "apple", b = "ball")
```

How this is possible to do in R?

Comment: You want the `transformed_data` to be a numeric vector? You can just do that by extracting the `value` column and assigning it the `names` of `name`.

Comment: Using dplyr: `data %>% pull(value, name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `tidyverse` approach given in the comment, so I'll include a base R approach here:

```
setNames(data[["value"]], data[["name"]])

      a       b 
"apple"  "ball"
```

Comment: Code golf :-)  `do.call(setNames, unname(data[2:1]))`

Answer (score 3):

Since you're tagging tidyverse in the question, you can use `deframe` from the tibble package:

```r
tibble::deframe(data)

      a       b 
"apple"  "ball"
```